# How to Check if a user is Logged in?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I've looked around for a while to try and find this but no luck. I have a chat room in my forum and I want to be able to show who is currently online, kinda like what Facebook does with their chat.

At first I made a row in my user table so that when they logged in it would set the value to 1 and if they hit logout it would be 0. But then I noticed that if the session ends and they have been logged out automatically then the value is still set to 1 as if they never logged out.

I was wondering if there's a better way to do this. I've seen some people say to setup a new table or record their last activity but I'm a little confused.

Comment: The question is a tad unclear but it's normal; check your `.ini` settings for sessions expiry.

Comment: I just explained that in my question. It doesn't work for those who don't click the logout button but the session expires instead.

Comment: I deleted my first comment about using boolean and posted another instead.

Comment: @SalmanZafar why did you remove the `session` tag I added? It's relevant to the question here and have defaced the question.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner check the revision.you'll find out who removed this.certainly not me

Comment: @SalmanZafar https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52956993/3 doesn't look like it to me. What am I not seeing? and mine https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52956993/2

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52956993/revisions

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner oh pardon.. session tag got removed by me unintentionally..

Answer (score 1):

You add an additional column for each user and in that column you store the time of last activity (in a form of timestamp, or whatever is convenient for you).

If time of user's last activity is no more than a minute (or so) less than NOW - the user is considered to be active.

You can play with parameters - it's not necessary a minute. Can be 5 minutes.

Depending on your application, you can just update that column for the user every time he opens some page, or have some js script on your chat page which will use AJAX or some other technique to send a request to the server to update that column - it will indicate that this particular user is active.

Comment: How would I get their last activity? How do I know the person is on my website? Like I said when they login I can update it in my table but if the session ends they haven't clicked log out and it will say they're still online.

Comment: Nevermund, I just made some AJAX code that runs when the page is loaded to make them online and then when the page closes it sets them to offline.

Comment: @TheWelshManc that's exactly what I was talking about. When the page is open, some AJAX code triggers some route every N seconds which updates user's status. If last update was more that N seconds ago - the user is offline.

Answer (score 0):

Use sessions. Example:

```
session_start();
// set timeout period in seconds
$inactive = 600;
// check to see if $_SESSION['timeout'] is set
if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) ) {
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
    if($session_life > $inactive)
    { session_destroy(); header("Location: logoutpage.php"); }
}
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
```

Answer (score 0):

You set up a php script that can verify they are still logged in via ajax, and have the user's browser send to it every so often. If they do not respond in the given time log them out.